# Building .Net core project on aws using codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

AWS Codebuild keeps throwing error - CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found

I'm trying to build a .net core web application. Build phase seems to be passing without problems, but there are no artifacts in S3 bucket

Here is my buildspec:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
        - echo "PRE-BUILD:::phase"         
  build:
    commands:
        - echo "BUILD:::phase" 
        - dotnet publish -c Debug -o ./build-output MyApp/MyApp.csproj   
artifacts:
  files: 
    - MyApp/build_output/**/*
```

Here is the build log:

```
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:15:49 Running command dotnet publish -c Debug -o ./build-output MyApp/MyApp.csproj 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.2.32702+c4012a063 for .NET Core 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 

  Restore completed in 7.5 sec for C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src274723887\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\MyApp\Model\Model.csproj. 
  Restore completed in 17.4 sec for C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src274723887\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\MyApp\Data\Data.csproj. 
  Restore completed in 17.39 sec for C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src274723887\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\MyApp\Services\Services.csproj. 
  Restore completed in 17.4 sec for C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src274723887\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\MyApp\MyApp.csproj. 

  Services -> C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src274723887\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\MyApp\Services\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Services.dll 
  Data -> C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src274723887\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\MyApp\Data\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Data.dll 
  Faraday.Waka3d -> C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src274723887\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\MyApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MyApp.dll 
  Faraday.Waka3d -> C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src274723887\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\MyApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MyApp.Views.dll 
  Faraday.Waka3d -> C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src274723887\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\MyApp\build-output\ 

[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:19 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED 
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:19 Phase context status code:  Message:  
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:19 Entering phase POST_BUILD  
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:22 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED 
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:22 Phase context status code:  Message:  
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:23 Expanding base directory path: . 
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:26 Assembling file list 
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:26 Expanding . 
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:29 Expanding file paths for base directory . 
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:29 Assembling file list 
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:29 Expanding Faraday.Waka3d/Faraday.Waka3d/build_output/**/* 
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:32 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED 
[Container] 2019/10/30 14:16:32 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found
```

I don't have a clue what is wrong here...

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration for the artifact references the wrong path. The published files went to `./build-output` as specified with your `dotnet publish -o ./build-output ...` but the artifact was specified to check for `MyApp/build_output/**/*`

You can verify your files by adding a `- 'dir ./build-output'` command to the build phase. This gives you an idea if your files are where they should be.